# Swift getting element type of generic array

Tags: swift, generics, types, casting

1. How to determine that Swift Generic is an array?
2. How to instantiate an array of specific elements?

I think I ended solutions. 
Thanks for any help.

In a similar situation:

```
var value: Any?
```

```
func get() -> T? {

    switch T.self {

    case is Int:
        return Int(self.value) as? T

    case let MT as MyProtocol.Type:

        return MT.init(self.value) as? T // Perfectly

    case let MTA as Array<MyProtocol>.Type: // <== Never case, why?

        let values = self.valueAsEEArray()
        return values?.map { TMA.Element.init($0) } as? T
//                                       ^ Protocol type 'Array<MyProtocol>.Element' (aka 'MyProtocol') cannot be instantiated
```

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    init(_ value: EE)
}
```

Comment: This approach looks pretty weird. The goal of generics is to get rid of extensive type checks. Consider to use a protocol with associated types and implement `get()` in all types which adopt the protocol.

Comment: It can't be initiated because the element type of the array is a `.Protocol` type, so you can't call `init` on it. But, you might be solving an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284459). How is this function used and what are you trying to do

Comment: @NewDev I use it as access to the value of `let id:Int = map["order_id"]`.
Func `get()` is a `subscript<T>(keypath: String?) -> T? {get set}`

Comment: @SergeySergeyev, I meant, what's beyond that? What are you actually trying to achieve? Why did you decide to use generics? How does `get` gets used? etc.... This is a very weird approach. Edit your question with these details.

Comment: @NewDev for data mapping. at the moment, the function correctly processes all data types except the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just write down one more function with return type array of T:

```
func get() -> [T] {
  //Code
}
```